# need help coming up with a regex solution in R

Tags: r, regex, string

I have several dates that I needed to convert. However I can't get the regex, but here is my alternate attempt that works, but it is unnecessarily long.

```r
library(stringr)
#date string vector, only two scenerios can be present
date <- c("3rd of June 18:09","22nd of January 22:19")

# substring will remove the string portion. I did not go
# with regex for this is because I am not that greate with it.

all_date_corrected <- c()

for(i in date){

  if(nchar(stringr::word(i, 1))>=4){
    x<- gsub(substr(i, start= 3, stop=7), "", i)

    all_date_corrected <- c(all_date_corrected,
                            format(strptime(x,"%d %B %H:%M",tz="GMT"),
                                   format="%m-%d %H:%M"))
  }
  else{
    x<- gsub(substr(i, start= 2, stop=6), "", i)

    all_date_corrected <- c(all_date_corrected,
                            format(strptime(x,"%d %B %H:%M",tz="GMT"),
                                   format="%m-%d %H:%M"))

  }

}

print(all_date_corrected) #[1] "06-03 18:09" "01-22 22:19"
```

I am pretty sure I can get rid of `substr` & `if- statement` with `gsub`. Here is my attempt with that.

```r
gsub("([0-9]+).*?([A-Z])", "\\1", date[1]) #[1] "3une 18:09"

gsub("([0-9]+).*?([A-Z])", "\\1", date[2]) #[1] "22anuary 22:19"
```

As you see, my pattern is keep eating up the letter and doesn't put space either. Would appreciate if somebody can help out. Thanks.

Comment: The package `lubridate` contains some functions to convert and parse dates. It's worth to take a look.

Comment: Hey, I couldn't find the appropriate function in there. I did go through its documentation :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this. It captures the day, month and time in three capturing groups and returns a string which is amenable to `strptime`:

```
strptime(gsub("^(\\d+)\\w+ of (\\w+) (.*)$", "\\1 \\2 \\3", date), "%d %B %H:%M")
#> [1] "2020-06-03 18:09:00 BST" "2020-01-22 22:19:00 GMT"
```

---

**Explanation**

- `^(\\d+)` Captures the leading digits from the string
- `\\w+ of` Matches but doesn't capture the `th of` or `rd of`
- `(\\w+)` Captures the full month name
- `(.$)$` Captures everything after the final space

The `"\\1 \\2 \\3"` means replace each string with the three capturing groups seperated by spaces, e.g. `"03 June 18:09"`. We can then capture this with `strptime` using `%d` for day, `%B` for month and `%H:%M` for the time.

Comment: Man....see, reduced to a single line. Why are you all so smart in SO? Thanks a lot. Could you please give little explanation on the regex? If that's ok :)

Comment: Thank you so much for adding a well-detailed explanation sir :)